# Homeomorphism from the whole plane to the open upper half plane.

Tags: general-topology

> Find a homeomorphism from the whole plane to the open upper half plane.

So I need to find a bicontinuous map $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R} \times[0, \infty)$. If I consider $f(x,y)=(x,e^y)$ then certainly $f$ is continuous since this is a $C^\infty$ function? Both component functions also have a continuous inverse, but neither one is defined at $(x,y)=(0,0)$? Is this a valid candidate or am I just mistaken here?

Comment: Huh? $f(0,0)=(0,1)$, so what is your problem?

Comment: I meant that $f^{-1}(0,0)$ isn't defined since $(\frac1x, \ln(y))$ both aren't defined at $(0,0)$. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: @DanielLi: $\langle 0,0\rangle$ isn’t in the open upper half plane in the first place. Your map should be thought of as a map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R\times(0,\to)$, not $\Bbb R\times[0,\to)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* no homeomorphism from $\Bbb R^2$ onto $\Bbb R \times [0,+\infty)$. But there is one from $\Bbb R^2$ onto $\Bbb R \times (0,+\infty)$, the latter is the **open** half plane (it's an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, while the former half-closed half-plane is not).

And for that latter $f(x,y)= (x, e^y)$ is a perfectly fine homeomorphism, with inverse $g(x,y)=(x, \ln y)$.

Answer (score 0):

suggest sending both to the open unit disc. The upper half plane goes by a Moebius transformation, one direction is $ \frac{z+i}{iz+1},$  the other way is just the reciprocal $ \frac{iz+1}{z+i}.$  The entire plane  just needs radial direction shrunk,  $(r,\theta )  \mapsto (\frac{r}{1+r}, \theta)$ works in one direction

Answer (score 0):

You can compose the *Cayley transform*, $\dfrac {z-i}{z+i}$, with your favorite homeomorphism between the disk and the plane.